# Wildcard sharing contracts in Windows 8 Metro

Tags: windows-runtime

I am wondering if it is possible to specify a wildcard sharing contract in Windows 8 metro. I would like to create an application that can receive every possible sharing request in Windows 8 (for debugging purposes), including custom streams from third party applications.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you pretty easily could. Until it comes to the custom streams/data.

ShareOperation.Data contains a list of strings that the datapackage contains. You could loop through them and do with you wish with the data. You just wouldn't be able to easily do some kind of If/Switch logic, since if you get custom data, it won't come up in the StandardDataFormats.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datapackageview.availableformats